# Extract numbers from list of lists

Tags: python, regex

I have this list of lists:

```
my_list=[['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%', '0,125%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', '?????'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2'],
 ['house', '0,2', '%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', 'boy'],
 ['house', '0,12%'],
 ['house', '4%.'],
 ['house', '4%.', '4.'],
 ['house', '0,2%”.']]
```

I would need to extract numbers based on words house and garden, in order to have something like:

```
{'garden': ['0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0.125', '0.02', '0.02', '0.02', '0.2', '0.2', '0,2'], 'house': ['0.2', '0.2', '0.2', '0.2', '0,2', '0,02', '0,02', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', ,'0,2','0,12', '4.', '4.', '4.', '0,2']}
```

How can I get these values?

Unfortunately this code:

```
result = defaultdict(list)

for l in my_list:
    k = None
    for v in l:
        if v in keywords:
            k = v
        if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+$', v): 
            num = v
    if k is not None:
        result[k].append(num)
```

it does not give me the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your regex. You need to remove the `$` anchor, which will fail to match a number if anything (e.g. the `%` character) is following the expected characters, namely `[0-9,.]`. The rest of the rest of the code can be simplified a bit, too:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

my_list=[['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%', '0,125%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', '?????'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2'],
 ['house', '0,2', '%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', 'boy'],
 ['house', '0,12%'],
 ['house', '4%.'],
 ['house', '4%.', '4.'],
 ['house', '0,2%".']]

result = defaultdict(list)
keywords = ['house', 'garden']
for l in my_list:
    numbers = [v for v in l if re.match(r'[0-9,.]+', v)]
    for v in l:
        if v in keywords:
            result[v].extend(numbers)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'house': ['0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,02%', '0,02%', '0,2%', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,12%', '4%.', '4%.', '4.', '0,2%".'], 'garden': ['0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,125%', '0,02%', '0,02%', '0,02%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
my_list=[['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
         ['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
         ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
         ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
         ['garden', '0,2%', '0,125%'],
         ['house', '0,2%', '?????'],
         ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
         ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
         ['garden', '0,02%'],
         ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
         ['garden', '0,2%'],
         ['house', '0,2'],
         ['house', '0,2', '%'],
         ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
         ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
         ['house', '0,2%', 'boy'],
         ['house', '0,12%'],
         ['house', '4%.'],
         ['house', '4%.', '4.'],
         ['house', '0,2%”.']]


my_dict = { 'garden':[], 'house':[]}
for lst in my_list:
    for s in lst:
        if any([n in s for n in '1234567890']):
            if 'house' in lst:
                my_dict['house'].append(s.replace('%',''))
            if 'garden' in lst:
                my_dict['garden'].append(s.replace('%',''))
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'garden': ['0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,125', '0,02', '0,02', '0,02', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2'], 'house': ['0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,02', '0,02', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2', '0,12', '4.', '4.', '4.', '0,2”.']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
my_list=[['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%', '0,125%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', '?????'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2'],
 ['house', '0,2', '%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', 'boy'],
 ['house', '0,12%'],
 ['house', '4%.'],
 ['house', '4%.', '4.'],
 ['house', '0,2%”.']]

house_list = []
garden_list = []

for arg in my_list: 
    if "house" in arg:
         for foo in arg:
              if foo != "house" and foo != "garden" and foo != "word:":
                   new_foo = ""
                   for char in foo:
                       if char in "1234567890,.":
                            new_foo += char 
                   if new_foo != "":
                        house_list.append(new_foo)
    if "garden" in arg:
          for foo in arg:
               if foo != "house" and foo != "garden" and foo != "word:":
                    new_foo = ""
                    for char in foo:
                         if char in "1234567890,.":
                              new_foo += char 
                    if new_foo != "":
                         garden_list.append(new_foo) 

output = {"house": house_list, "garden": garden_list}
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpler way could be this:

```
my_list=[['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['word:', 'house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%', '0,125%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', '?????'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,02%'],
 ['garden', '0,02%'],
 ['house', 'garden', '0,2%'],
 ['garden', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2'],
 ['house', '0,2', '%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', 'garden', 'kids', '0,2%'],
 ['house', '0,2%', 'boy'],
 ['house', '0,12%'],
 ['house', '4%.'],
 ['house', '4%.', '4.'],
 ['house', '0,2%”.']]


output = {'garden': [],
          'house': []}
for line in my_list:
    for keyword in output.keys():
        if keyword in line:
            for element in line:
                if element[0].isnumeric():
                    output[keyword].append(element)
```

Output:

```
{'garden': ['0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,125%', '0,02%', '0,02%', '0,02%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%'], 'house': ['0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,02%', '0,02%', '0,2%', '0,2', '0,2', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,2%', '0,12%', '4%.', '4%.', '4.', '0,2%”.']}
```

Explanation:
I loop over the lists (`line`) in you list, then loop over the desired keywords (`'garden'` and `'house'`), then I check if that `keyword` is in the `line`, if so, I loop over `line`'s `element` to find an `element` which starts with a number (this is my assumption), if so, I append it to the `output` dictionary.